# Bash variable assignment not working

Tags: string, bash, date, concatenation

I have a Bash script that takes todays date as command line argument, calculates the previous day and creates a hive query to create a table at a certain location on hdfs.  I can't seem to get the concatenation of strings right.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $1
onedaybehind=`date -d "$1 - 1 days" +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $onedaybehind

hivequery="CREATE TABLE abc(id bigint, name string )
           ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
           LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/data/abc/"        
echo $hivequery
st = $hivequery$onedaybehind
echo $st
```

Both the variables onedaybehind and hivequery are printed properly but it cant identify the variable st.  i tried using quotes and brackets too.

Ideally i want to generate the string :

```
CREATE TABLE abc( id bigint, name string)
        ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
         LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/data/abc/2015-11-15;'"
```

(With a semicolon and single quote in the end).  I run this program by : sh test.sh 2015=11-16.

Please help, not sure if its the casting date to string that is a problem but I can't get the concatenation right.

Comment: Remove space around `=` to make it `st="$hivequery$onedaybehind"`

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught that for you without needing to ask here.

Comment: Also, quotes. `echo $foo` and `echo "$foo"` are not the same thing. (Shellcheck would have caught that too).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the pointer.  Shellcheck is interesting. Many thanks again!